# Change parent page from within an iframe

Tags: php, javascript

I'm trying to use an iframe to process a log in, and change the parent page depending on the output. I've traced the javascript to here:

```
function results(status)
{
   req = new XMLHttpRequest();
   req.open('GET', '../design/loginbox.php', false);
   req.send(null);

   alert(req.responseText);

   top.document.getElementByID['loginbar'].innerHTML = req.responseText;
}
```

I know this isn't cross compatible or anything, but at the moment I'm just testing. The alert shows the correct output, however, the parent page never changes. Can anyone see where I am going wrong?

Thanks, Piepieonline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
top.document.getElementById('loginbar').innerHTML = req.responseText;
```

here `getElementById` is a method... you have to call it, not use it like an array.

Comment: Indeed, this is the answer. The corrected line is:
    "top.document.getElementById('loginbar').innerHTML = req.responseText;". Thanks so much for that! Strange problem - in Google Chrome, this works on first load, but if I log out and try again, it doesn't work until I reopen the browser?

Comment: Scratch that, the error must have been elsewhere. It all works now, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's a typo, but you should have `getElementById('loginbar')` The 'D' shouldn't be capitol and you should use () and not []

Answer (score 0):

The only way i know to pass that kind off info, is via base64 encode
 [base64encode](http://www.webtoolkit.info/javascript-base64.html)

you can do like:

```
window.parent.location = '?loginbar='+Base64.encode('"+req.responseText+"');
```

and you have to decode in the other window:

```
var loginbar = Base64.decode(this.utils.getUrlVar('loginbar'));
```

PD: utils.getUrlVar, loop the window.search ... and i suppose that response is a json